# Regex: match string unless it contains a word

Tags: regex

A fairly simple regex rule I'm trying to create. However, I'm only finding tips for captures of the word and not whole phrases.

I want to capture all lines that contains `red` unless it also contains `ball`. It doesn't matter in what order. I just only need to capture `red` only without `ball`.

```
I have a red ball
I have a red cup
I have a green ball
This cup that I have is red
```

The bonus would be a regex rule for the inverse of this. Capture `red` and `ball` not not `ball` only.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Unfortunately it's being downvoted with a link to another post that isn't quite the same question. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Try this `grep red file | grep -v ball`

Comment: This is some regex for a yaml file. I can't use grep

Comment: [mcve] sil vous plait. Show your effort.

Comment: I would show my effort but I don't know how to do it unfortunately.
It's a hard to google example. A lot of things are talking about negative/positive lookhead but I don't care if it's in front or behind. I can't have it match at all.

Comment: You can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), e.g. `red(?!.*ball)`. Whether or not it will work your case depends on the language and regex engine that you are using. Please clarify that if you want to receive better answers

Comment: `^(?!.*\bball\b).*\bred\b.*`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini your regex only works if the word `red` precedes the word `ball`. The OP also wants the inverse.

Comment: @ctwheels: sure, and also lacks word boundaries. This is why I posted a comment and not an answer. You can go ahead and post yours as an answer :-)

Comment: `^(?=.*?\bball\b).*?\bred\b.*$` - Do I get the bonus points? ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't quite work either. It doesn't match with any results using pythex. I appreciate the help though!